# Configuring lint4j

Tags: java, maven

I have to use lint4j static analyzer tool in my project. I was referring http://www.jutils.com/maven-plugin/ link to setup the same.
But this does not tell me how to configure reports in lint4j. I am new to maven and have not used maven extensively.
I have done below steps so far.

1. Created a lint4j plugin jar folder in my local repository. Added below dependency in pom.xml of my project.

   ```xml
   <dependency>
     <groupId>lint4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>jutils-lint4j-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.1</version>
   </dependency>

   <reports>
     <report>jutils-lint4j-plugin</report>
   </reports>
   ```
2. mvn clean install works fine for the project.

But what needs to be done to view the report now?

Answer (score 0):

Assembling bits on information scattered all over the web, I believe doing `mvn site` should be enough (at least according to [Maven Project Info Reports Plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/usage.html))

**Notes:**

- I could not find a working version of this plugin; the only place that hosts it ([SoapUI SVN repo](http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/lint4j/jutils-lint4j-plugin/1.3.1/)) seems to have a broken .jar (*"plugin descriptor not found"*)
- version `1.3.1` sounds strange since [the official download page](http://www.jutils.com/download.html) only mentions version 0.9.1
- As of [version 4.0.0 of Maven POM](https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd) `<reports>` element is deprecated (and ignored), should be replaced with `<reporting>`. More info on the newer configuration syntax can be found [in the official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/plugin-info.html#Usage).
- The project seems to have been abandoned since 2007; I'm sure there are better tools for the task, I wouldn't be surprised if this plugin stopped working due to changes in Java or Maven at some point